# Make an API call to service once the specific terraform module is destroyed using custom terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform

I am using a custom terraform provider to make an HTTP API call to service when a terraform module is completed or destroyed.
I am able to successfully make an API call to service when the module-a is provisioned post that  custom_resource_complete is created which makes an API call.

Whereas in the case of destroying scenario where I am using option -target="module.module-a" to destroy the module. What I thought once the module is destroyed it will also delete custom_resource_destroy which will eventually make an API call. But here what happens is called
first and then only module-a is destroyed so I am unable to capture it.

I tried other options like -target="custom_resource_destroy.module-a-destroy" no luck this will destroy only this resource but not the module

My requirement is I need to make an API call to service once the specific terraform module is destroyed. Below is my terraform main.tf

```
{
    "provider": {
        "aws": {

        },
        "customprovider": {
            "url": "some url"
        }
    },

    "module": {
        "module-a": {
            "source": "./module-a"
        }
    },
    "resource": {
        "custom_resource_complete": {
            "module-a-complete": {

                "output": "${module.module-a.output}"
            }
        },
        "custom_resource_destroy": {
            "module-a-destroy": {

                "output": "${module.module-a.output}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Provider Go Lang Snippet

```
func resourceCustomResourceDestroy() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        Create: resourceCustomResourceDestroyCreate,
        Read:   resourceCustomResourceDestroyRead,
        Update: resourceCustomResourceDestroyUpdate,
        Delete: resourceCustomResourceDestroyDelete,
        }
    }


func resourceCustomResourceDestroyDelete(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) error { 
    
    // HTTP Request to service
    }
```

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are asking, but this would generally be implemented in the `Delete` function that you reference in your `schema.Resource`.

Comment: Hi Matt, In the Delete function I have defined API call. When I hit terraform destroy -target="module.module-a"  the delete function of resource custom_resource_destroy is called at the beginning itself after that only the actual module is destroyed.